# Shnayim Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

וידבר    =    222

Answer (score 6):

There are 222 pesukim in Megillas Koheles

Answer (score 2):

The eighteen years following any leap year have 222 months.

Comment: Compare http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6734

Answer (score 1):

Reportedly, 222 Jews from [Bergen-Belsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergen-Belsen_concentration_camp) arrived in Haifa in July of 1944 in an exchange deal between Germany and Britain for German citizens in Palestine.

Answer (score 1):

[Reportedly](http://books.google.com/books?id=oBpOAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA48&dq=auditorium), in 1909, 222 organizations sent delegates to a New York Jewish community convention.